# How to Uninstall cPanel from Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-8.04, uninstall

Hi is there any way I can remove cPanel from my ubuntu installation? Any scripts for this purpose?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Then why don't you **move** it to a more relevant site; e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com  or  https://superuser.com instead of shutting down any useful discussion about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are no scripts to uninstall it, as it does a significant amount of modifications to the underlying OS. It is recommended to just reinstall the OS if you want to remove it.

Comment: #yum erase 'centos*'

make sure to edit the /etc/yum.conf to remove the packages listed in the exclude section

[main]
exclude= ..


As per https://paragasu.wordpress.com/2015/05/27/how-to-uninstall-cpanel-from-centos-6-server/

Comment: I disagree with the reasoning behind closing this question.  cPanel in a VPS is like a *rootkit*! Therefore, I don't think that " This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel. – HopelessN00b Jan 13 '15 at 21:02" if you're trying to **remove this rootkit from your Server**!  

Additional, useful information at:  

http://www.askapache.com/hacking/uninstall-cpanel.html